# resource files under webapp/WEB-INF or src/main/resources?

Tags: java

In my project i see some xmls under  `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` while some under `src/main/resources`.
Is there any convention what kind of file should go under these location

Answer (score 5, accepted):

src/main/resources contains Application/Library resources.

The Servlet 2.4 specification says this about WEB-INF:

A special directory exists within the application hierarchy named WEB-INF. This directory contains all things related to the application that aren’t in the document root of the application. The WEB-INF node is not part of the public document tree of the application. No file contained in the WEB-INF directory may be served directly to a client by the container. However, the contents of the WEB-INF directory are visible to servlet code using the getResource and getResourceAsStream method calls on the ServletContext, and may be exposed using the RequestDispatcher calls.

Comment: Application/Library resources mean 3rd party library resources used in project. Is it?

Comment: Yes. If you want them in your classpath. scr/main/resources is a place where you put your images, sounds, templates, language bundles, textual and binary files used by the source code